# What is intermolecular distance in water?

Tags: thermodynamics, liquid-state

I am wondering what is an average intermolecular distance in liquid water (say under normal pressure and room temperature).

I need just order of magnitude. A reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

One [mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_%28unit%29) of liquid water has a mass of 18 grams (two hydrogen atoms with mass 1, one oxygen with 16), occupies 18cm³ and contains [roughly 6e23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) molecules.

So, the average single molecule occupies 3e-23cm³. If you assume that to be a cube (good enough for the order of magnitude), you get a dimension of 3.1e-8cm, or 0.31 nanometer.

And that's the average distance between the water molecules.

Answer (score 4):

In liquids the molecules are packed densely.
Therefore the intermolecular distance is about
equal to the size of the molecules
(which for [water](https://www.google.de/search?q=what+is+the+size+of+a+water+molecule%3F) is around $3 \cdot 10^{-10}$ m).